# Jinja template to iterate multiple column and generate the case statement

Tags: jinja2, dbt

`Hi Team,

we need to calculate the kpI's based on a set of attributes maintained in table

A sample dataset will look like, we have close to 10 fields in the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCCkT.png)

The final KPI select statement is like below order is the main table and we need to check whether the values is maintained on the KPI rule table or not.

```
`select case ( when orders.customer = kpitable.customer type and 
      orders.order type = kpitable.order type and 
     orders.region = kpitable.region ) then order.cost else 0 end as cost
case when orders.order type = kpitable.order type then order.cost as return
from orders `
```

I was trying to write DBT macro to this. the idea a we will pass the required selection list to the macro and the macro will dynamically generate the case statement.

```
`{% set selection_pairs = ['customer type','ordertype','region'] %}
{% set selection_list = selection_list|join(", ") %}
{% set table  = orders %}
{% set sql = "select " + selection_list + " from " + table  %}
{%- set Filter_set = dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict(sql1) -%}`your text`
{% for key, values in Filter_set.items() %}
{% set a = "o." +  key  + "=" + values[0] + " and" %}
{{ log(a, info=True) }}
{% end for %}
```

`On the for loop I was not able to generate the case statement by combining the multiple selection criteria and pass back. could you please suggest some input.`

Comment: Could it be easier with a join?